# configure MinGW with Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, gcc, mingw32

I have searched a lot about this and read most of the available answers for similar problem but I still couldn't solve it. Therefore, any help will be helpful.

I am using Eclipse Mars(Latest version after Luna) on Windows 7

MinGW is installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin".

Environment variable "Path" contains "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;..."
Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery->CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings : command to get compiler specs
${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
manually doing gcc -E -P -v -dD in cmd from any directory gives
.
.
Target: mingw32
.
.

**Errors:**

> Program g++/gcc not found in PATH
>
> I make a C++ project, add a file with hello world program in it.
>
> I get errors "unresolved inclusion " and 'printf' could not be resolved.

*comment if any other details required*

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing everything correctly.

TWO SUGGESTIONS:

1. Take a look at this link, and see if you missed anything regarding the MinGW/GCC install:

   https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html
2. Otherwise, consider deleting (or simply renaming) your current Eclipse and installing the CDT (Eclipse for C/C++ Developers) version instead:

   http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
3. For whatever it's worth, here are a couple of screenshots from my property settings (I'm able to create and successfully build a new C project):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply!! :)  
 For some reason my MinGW does not have msys folder the sub folders in MinGW are   
bin,doc,include,lib,libexec,mingw32,share and files  
 mingwvars.bat,readme,copying...  
 I am trying to configure OpenCV android library with eclipse and configuring CDT is a part of it therefore switching to fresh Eclipse inbuilt with CDT will be difficult  
 Please suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is simply because of MinGW path include white spaces in it. just reinstalling MinGW on Root directory "c:\MinGW"will solve your problem.
 install MinGW with basic setup packages select "mingw-developer-toolkit, mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc-g++, msys-base". complete installation. 
 restart your pc. then check your eclipse settings.
I hope your problem is already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such problems,you need to set environment variable, In path add your MinGW location, if you haven't downloaded MinGW go here for downloading MinGW: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files

Simple solution is:

[image]

For more and detailed information to fix your problem, it worked for me!

**Visit here:**

http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-install-mingw-msys-and-eclipse-on-windows/